# Android BindView elements return as null object references

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, null

I am implementing a project which requires visualizing data with a recycler view. I am having an issue with the charactersFragment (which queries character data from StarWars api) and presents them on the fragment with the use of an adapter:

```
@BindView(R.id.rv_characters)
RecyclerView recycler;

@BindView(R.id.progress_characters)
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

The api responses with onCharactersLoadedSuccess() :

```
@Override
public void onCharactersLoadedSuccess(List<Character> characters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received characters: " + characters.size());
    switch (characterPage) {
        case 1:
```

...

```
        case 9:
            for (int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
                AllCharacters.add(characters.get(i));
            }
            characterPage = 0;
            Log.d("CHARACTERS 9", "RECIEVED CHARACTERS OF PAGE 9 WITH SUCCESS!");
            Collections.sort(AllCharacters, new Comparator<Character>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
                    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                }
            });
            setRecyclerAdapter(AllCharacters);
            break;
    }
}
```

And then i am setting the recycleradapter to show the data:

```
   private void setRecyclerAdapter(List<Character> characters) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    recycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

All the above code is handled on charactersFragment.

For some reason i am getting both viwes (progressBar and Recycler) as not initialized (null references). What is the issue? How can i fix this?

Comment: I tried to set both with getActvity().findViewById but they still appear as null after the assigning operations...

Comment: have you maked before in `onCreate` `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml)` ? and `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

Comment: Its a fragment so the assigning happes in the onCreateView with an inflater...

Comment: have you then maked `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` ?

Comment: Yes i have set the ButterKnife.bind(this, view) command...

Comment: could you please post the error log here? for me it seems as modification from wrong Thread, and not NullPointer exception.